# Error "The value you selected is not a valid choice" in Avatar Kit field settings

Tags: media

I just tried [Avatar Kit 8.x-1.0-beta2](https://www.drupal.org/project/avatars/releases/8.x-1.0-beta2). I created a few Gravatar generator presets but after adding the Avatar Generator field to the user entity and trying to select one of the Avatar Generator radio options I get the error "The value you selected is not a valid choice" on clicking "Save settings". The same error occurs when trying to edit a user. Here's what I'm seeing:

[image: Avatar kit field settings error]

Comment: Sorry I just read on the Avatar Kit module page that the developers want issues posted to their Github issue queue instead of here, so I've reposted there https://github.com/dpi/avatars/issues/25